# Why are UWP class library project references are getting copied to the main project?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, nuget, uwp, windows-10-universal

I've faced with one issue related to the Universal Windows Platform that drives me nuts.

Let's say I have two projects in my solution -- the first one is Universal Windows app (**TestApp**), and the second one is Universal Windows class library (**TestClassLibrary**). The **TestApp** has a reference to the **TestClassLibrary**. The **TestClassLibrary** refers to a **Newtonsoft.Json** NuGet package (it could be any other package).

[image]

And now the strange part. Any reference inside **TestClassLibrary** becomes public to the **TestApp**. I can use any NewtonsoftJson-specific namespaces in **TestApp** classes, despite the fact that neither **TestApp.csproj**, nor **project.json** don't have a single reference to Newtonsoft.Json whatsoever. This violates **TestClassLibrary** incapsulation, so that its implmementation details (i.e. referenced libraries) become public, and I don't want that.

The question is -- is this a feature of UWP class libraries and where I can read about it? Or is this a NuGet bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any reference inside TestClassLibrary becomes public to the TestApp. I can use any NewtonsoftJson-specific namespaces in TestApp classes.

I can reproduce this issue by the steps as following:

1. Create two projects following your example, make sure the following options are checked in the Option window.
   [image]
2. Intellisense does not work for Newtonsoft.Json inside TestApp project. However, TestApp build successfully.

   [image]
3. Reopen the solution, both Intellisense and build works.

   [image]

This should be an issue of NuGet, I found a similar open issue on Nuget GitHub issues page (https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1629).